# How to pass Node js string variable to a SQL Server stored procedure input parameter using Node.js

Tags: node.js, sql-server, datetime

I want to pass Nodejs variable `cur_wtr_mk_val` (which is storing a timestamp value) to  input parameter in my SQL Server stored procedure which is of `datetime` data type. But when I am using the code shown here, I get the following error:

> System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Functions.d-we2bidl-func03. System.Private.CoreLib: Result: Failure
> Exception: Error converting data type nvarchar to datetime.
>
> Stack: RequestError: Error converting data type nvarchar to datetime.
>
> at handleError (C:\Users\INPTV\Desktop\deepsea_function\node_modules\mssql\lib\tedious\request.js:384:15)
> at Connection.emit (node:events:527:28)
> at Connection.emit (C:\Users\INPTV\Desktop\deepsea_function\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1079:18)
> at RequestTokenHandler.onErrorMessage (C:\Users\INPTV\Desktop\deepsea_function\node_modules\tedious\lib\token\handler.js:365:21)
> at Readable. (C:\Users\INPTV\Desktop\deepsea_function\node_modules\tedious\lib\token\token-stream-parser.js:26:33)
> at Readable.emit (node:events:527:28)
> at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:315:12)
> at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:289:9)
> at Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:228:10)
> at next (node:internal/streams/from:98:31).

My code looks like this:

```
module.exports = async function (context, req) {

 //Authenticating SQL Server
   const sql = require('mssql')
   const sqlConfig = {
   server: "",
   port: ,
   user: "",
   password: "",
   database: "",
   options: {
   enableArithAbort:true,
   encrypt: true, // for azure
  trustServerCertificate: false // change to true for local dev / self-signed certs
},
  pool: {
  max: 10,
  min: 0,
  idleTimeoutMillis: 30000
  }
};

sql.on('error', err=> {
  console.log(err.message)
})

//Fetching Current Water mark value from ADX table
const results = await client.execute("VesselTelemetry","VesselTelemetry_DS_Data | extend 
  Enqueued_time = todatetime(ingested_timestamp) | summarize max_Enqueued_time =  
  max(Enqueued_time)");
  const obj1 = results.primaryResults[0].toString();
  const obj2 = JSON.parse(obj1);
  var cur_wtr_mk_val = obj2.data[0].max_Enqueued_time; // I need to pass this variable storing 
   // timestamp value 2022-07-16T13:37:36.212Z to the sql stored procedure datetime input 
  //  parameter


 //Calling the stored procedure
 let sql_config = await sql.connect(sqlConfig)
 let sp_query = await sql_config.request().query(`exec 
 WW_DL_MIG_CFG.SP_DB_INC_MIG_DL_PIP_AUD_DELTA_INF @LastModifiedtime = "+cur_wtr_mk_val+"  `)
 const sp_stringify = JSON.stringify(sp_query);
 const sp_parse = JSON.parse(sp_stringify);
 console.log(sp_parse);
 }
```

How to fix this error?

Comment: Have you read the [input parameters](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#input-name-type-value) portion of the mssql documentation yet?

Comment: Yes I triedby adding input parameter as given in the document but that is not working